# Windows Forms Toolbox System.TypeInitializationException with UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, typeinitializeexception

I am using VS2015 to work on a Project using UserControls for Windows Forms.
The last time I used the Controls everything worked fine and it had no display errors at all. However after restarting VS the Toolbox was unable to display the Controls.

When I start to add the Controls to other Forms it displays the error:

> Error while creating the component *ctrlObjectEditor*.
>
> Error message: System.TypeInitializationException
>
> The Typeinitializer for "*project*.Log.LoggerHost" threw an Exception.
>
> ... *(only rough translation)*

When I run the Programm it works fine but I can not edit this in the Toolbox.

The Controls are all in the same Assembly.
I have found other Questions but they dont seem to work for me. (e.g. AnyCPU, x64, x86, removing Logger from Controls)

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the answer myself.

The Class FileLogger had a static Parameter filled with the value:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
```

It seems this Method causes an Exception when run by the designer so I replaced it with:

```
try
{
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()?.Location);
    return Path.Combine(dir, "Logs");
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    return "C:\\Logs";
}
```

And this seems to work.